# Не работает оснастка на терминальном сервере

Tags: windows

Сегодня при попытке на сервер открыть оснастку конфигурация узла сеансов, я получил ошибку не удалось получить параметры данного сервера узла сеансов удаленных рабочих столов.
У кого-то такое уже было, как решать?

Answer (score 1):

Коллеги, в итоге нашел я в чем оказалась проблема, в итоге был [поврежден репозиторий WMI](http://pyatilistnik.org/ne-rabotaet-osnastka-konfiguratsiya-uzla-seansov-rdp/), а как оказалось, на данный сервер была прилеплена политика, по WMI фильтру, а так как она не отрабатывала, то и другие то же блокировались, вот такой глюк системы. Надеюсь кому-то пригодится.